# C# search directly from textbox

Tags: c#

I had created a searching query that displays data to other textboxes but it wont let me type a number and it is automatically searching .. please help this is my code

Here is my code:

```
private void txtBarajKod_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MySqlConnection connection = Connection.prevzemiKonekcija();
    connection.Open();
try
{
    MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable tabela;
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    string query = "SELECT * FROM artikli WHERE barcode  like '%" + txtBarajKod.Text + "%'";
    command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    tabela = new DataTable();

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    //dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;
    //adapter.Fill(tabela);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBarajKod.Text))
        return;

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        txtBarajKod.Text = reader.GetString("barcode");
        txtNaziv.Text = reader.GetString("ProductName");
        txtCena.Text = reader.GetString("SellPrice");
    }
    else
    {
        txtBarajKod.Text = "";
        txtNaziv.Text = "";
        txtCena.Text = "";
        txtKolicina.Text = "";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: is your input type a number?

Comment: yes it is an number

Comment: side note watch out for SQL injection

Comment: The problem is that when i enter something on the textbox that has this code inside of it , it automatically searches it wont let me type first and then search but it is randomly searching data from the database

Comment: fire the event on textbox_leave instead of on change perhaps (and also fire it on the enter key press too?)...or have a button instead...definitely use a parameter for SQL injection concern

Comment: "The problem is that when i enter something ..... it automatically searches it wont let me type first". You need a different event. First you need to define how exactly you intend to initiate the search. By pressing ENTER  e.g.?

Comment: The problem is that i cannot use a button for this it should automatically search from the textbox without pressing a button

Comment: It recieves data from a barcode reader !!!

Comment: " it should automatically search" it seems that you have achieved that. I read in your post "but it wont let **me** type a number" then you scream "It recieves data from a barcode reader !!! " are you the barcode reader? or are we supposed to understand that **txtBarajKod** means "It recieves data from a barcode reader !!! " ??????

Comment: Let me explain again.. If i enter anything in the textbox (in this case the txtBarajKod) i randomly shows data from my database

Comment: This is how this event works. You can read it in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)  You still haven't explained how you would like to initiate the search?....!

Answer (score 0):

TextChanged event is fired every time you type something. You have few solutions:

1. Use TextBox Leave event instead of TextChanged
2. If your barcodes are all the same length (probably are), you can add `if(txtBarajKod.Text.Lenght < your_barcode_size){ return; }`
3. Use Keypress method, and if Enter is pressed (this would be best option if your input is barcode reader, since it add Enter key press in the end), then run this check you wrote:

   `private void KeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
       {
           //Place your code here
       }
   }`

Comment: I entered the code on the  private void txtBarajKod_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: and you are telling me how to search using keypress

Comment: Read my answer carefully, I gave you few options of what you can do. Option 2 is to add length check in your current event @J.Don

Comment: i want to create something like in this vide : https://youtu.be/z2NwrYwbyAA?t=204

Comment: @J.Don if all your barcodes are the same length (like item codes in the video are), you can use option 2 from my answer. If you want to have drop down to choose item based on your typing, you'll have to change the control tou're using...

Answer (score -1):

The initial value of the text box is an empty string. The event is firing when this initial value is set. As a result, your where condition includes the clause, `WHERE barcode like '%%'`, which selects everything.

To avoid this, add the following code to the beginning of the method:

```
If txtBarajKod.Text = String.Empty Then
    Return
End If
```

Although, as others have pointed out in the comments, this design is intrinsically unsafe. It provides an open door for [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).